# How can I use "if __name__ == '__main__':" in my code below?

Tags: spyder, bayesian, pymc3

After I run my code I get a warning as:

"RuntimeError:
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
in the main module:

if **name** == '**main**':
freeze_support()
...

The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
is not going to be frozen to produce an executable."

**My question is that how and where I should add this line of code to avoid this warning/error in my code below:**

```
from scipy import stats, optimize
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

#from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from theano import shared

np.random.seed(9)

#Load the Data
dataset = pd.read_csv(‘PV-PCM.csv’)
X=dataset.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,4]].values
y=dataset.iloc[:,5].values

X_tr, X_te, y_tr, y_te = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=42)

#Shapes
X.shape, y.shape, X_tr.shape, X_te.shape

#Preprocess data for Modeling
shA_X = shared(X_tr)

#Generate Model
linear_model = pm.Model()

with linear_model:
# Priors for unknown model parameters

alpha = pm.Normal("alpha", mu=y_tr.mean(),sd=10)
betas = pm.Normal("betas", mu=0, sd=1000, shape=X.shape[1])
sigma = pm.HalfNormal("sigma", sd=100) # you could also try with a HalfCauchy that has longer/fatter tails
mu = alpha + pm.math.dot(betas, X_tr.T)
likelihood = pm.Normal("likelihood", mu=mu, sd=sigma, observed=y_tr)
step = pm.NUTS()
trace = pm.sample(1000, step)

chain = trace[100:]
#pm.traceplot(chain);

#Traceplot
pm.traceplot(trace)

ppc = pm.sample_prior_predictive(samples=1000, random_seed=9)

pm.plot_posterior(trace, figsize = (12, 10))
sns.kdeplot(y_tr, alpha=0.5, lw=4, c=‘b’)
for i in range(100):
sns.kdeplot(ppc[‘likelihood’][i], alpha=0.1, c=‘g’)

alpha_pred = chain[‘alpha’].mean()
betas_pred = chain[‘betas’].mean(axis=0)

y_pred = alpha_pred + np.dot(betas_pred, X_tr.T)
```

Thank you all.